# GmailApp not returning all messages in Thread

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a Gmail script running that is supposed to return the subject line and message body from all e-mail messages with the label "taxes/payments".  However, It is only returning the first message in the thread because I'm using 'getFirstMessageSubject()' instead of 'getSubject()'.

I think I'm confused about how to use different classes in the GmailApp framework (I'm new to programming).  When I try to display the Subject lines from the messages I store in the variable 'mes', I get an error saying "getSubject() is not a function".  Can someone clear this confusion up for me so I understand how to use the different classes?  I have read through the [class descriptions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getSubject()) and tried various examples but am not understanding how it all fits together.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Load Emails", functionName: "getEmails"} ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu("GetOrders", menuEntries);
}

function getEmails(){
  // Log the subject lines of your Inbox
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("taxes/payments");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  var row = 2;

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()); 
    Logger.log(threads[i].getMessages()); //returns data of type: GmailMessage[]
    var mes= threads[i].getMessages();//store the messages in the variable 'mes' 
    Logger.log(mes.getSubject());


    sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject());
    sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(threads[i].getLastMessageDate());

    var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
    
    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++) {
      var msg = messages[j].getPlainBody();      
      sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(msg);
    }
  row++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is not in your use of the classes, but rather how you're handling the data!

---

You are properly iterating over each thread of your `GmailThread[]`, with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
```

And are then receiving an array in return of `GmailMessage`s (`GmailMessage[]`) through [getMessages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getmessages):

```
var mes = threads[i].getMessages();
```

And are then writing the subject and message date in Column A and B:

```
sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject());
sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(threads[i].getLastMessageDate());
```

**You then go on to write each message body into the same cell of Column C:**

```
for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++) {
  var msg = messages[j].getPlainBody();      
  sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(msg);
}
```

**This means you will only see the first message body of the thread.**

---

---

**Solution:**

You can try:

```
function getEmails(){

  const label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("taxes/payments");
  const threads = label.getThreads();

  let row = 2;

  for (let i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    const messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {

      const msg = messages[j].getPlainBody(); 

      sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject());
      sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(threads[i].getLastMessageDate());     
      sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(msg);

      row++;
    
    }
  
  }

}
```

By moving `row++` into the `for` loop of each message, each message of each thread will be set to your sheet and not overwriting each other. If you find `row++` isn't working, you can try `row += 1`.

Moving forward, a more efficient solution would be to [set your values all at once](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) in the [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) versus one cell at a time:

```
function getEmails(){

  const label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("taxes/payments");
  const threads = label.getThreads();

  let row = 2;

  for (let i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    const messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {

      sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 3).setValues([
        [
          threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject(),
          threads[i].getLastMessageDate(),
          messages[j].getPlainBody()
        ]
      ])

      row++;
    
    }
  
  }

}
```

Additionally, you are currently only using the `.getLastMessageDate()`, in your situation it might make more sense to use the `.getDate()` method for each message:

```
    [
      threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject(),
      messages[j].getDate(),
      messages[j].getPlainBody()
    ]
```

---

```
function getEmails() {

  GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("taxes/payments")
          .getThreads()
          .forEach(thread => {

            const threadSubject = thread.getFirstMessageSubject()

            thread.getMessages()
                  .forEach(message => 
                    sheet.appendRow(threadSubject, message.getDate(), message.getPlainBody())
                  )

          })

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation.  This type of answer really helps me learn how to write much cleaner code.  Great solution!

Comment: You did a great job for being 'new to programming'. Keep going!